# ERROR: column "included" does not exist in table when using parenthesis in a CASE expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I get this error

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "included" does not exist in planning.core_rg

when attempting to write the following SQL query with a `CASE` expression. `Included` is the value that would be assigned if the value does not fall in either the first or second WHEN conditions it is not a column in the table. I do not understand why the query is looking for a column named "Included" in the table.

```
SELECT 
    geo, region, pod,
    CASE 
        WHEN acct_pod IN ('NYC', 'Brooklyn' 'Queens', 'N. NJ' )
            THEN 'Excluded'
        WHEN acct_pod IN ('Hartford', 'New Haven', 'West Chester')
            THEN 'Developing'
        ELSE "Included"
    END AS "Pod Type"
FROM
    planning.core_rg
```

Comment: ELSE 'Included'

Comment: I.e. use single quotes for string literals. Double quotes are for _delimited identifiers_, e.g. column names.

Comment: This was the fix. Oversight on my part here. Thanks!

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.